# TFS 2013: Get all work items below a certain parent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

how can I define a query in TFS 2013 (Team Explorer 2013) to get all items as a list below a certain toplevel workitem:

```
|--+-Parent 1
   |
   |--+-Child 1
   |  |--Child of Child 1
   |
   |--+-Child 2
   |  |
   |  |--Child of Child 2
   |
   | ...
```

Result:

- Child 1
- Child of Child 1
- Child 2
- Child of Child 2

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Konrad

Comment: I made it work with Fenton's solution but selecting  "Work Items and Direct Links", not "Tree of work items"

Answer (score 34):

Step 1 - Select "Tree of work items"

Step 2 - Set up the query as usual for the top level work items, for example only "Epic" work items with id `4247` (whatever you like really).

Step 3 - Under "Filters for linked work items" you can exclude descendent items, for example you could show only PBIs, or only bugs etc.

[image: Example Query]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a "Tree of Work Items" type of query.

Comment: If I use the tree, I couldn't filter out some childs I don't want (e.g. of a certain type like "Feature") ... I need it in a pure list, to get the total count of items.

Comment: @Konrad Can't you limit type with that `Work Item Type` that's displayed in the answer from @Fenton?

Answer (score 2):

Konrad,

The most simple way to learn how build this querys is: on backlog turn on features, user story  and task, I know you want features, then click create a query, give a name.
That query show you how to build one with tree and WIT's with same type like sub-query, for example.

After you do this, tell us what you want to refine.

Comment: I created about 100s of queries with tfs the last years. so let me clearify this: I've a topmost item (feature) and under this many tasks and bugs and other features with task and bugs under and so on. ... If I use the tree view query, i get a well formed tree with all 3 WIT in a structure. But I only need the tasks and the bugs ... so I want to "filter out" all feature WITs but without loosing the tasks and bugs on the 2nd, 3rd, ... level under the topmost feature. Why? Because I want the correct number of tasks/bugs as the count without the structuring feature work items.

Comment: You need the tasks and bugs items that are children of a feature is on the second level, or children of a feature, but do not want to appear a feature, is it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. All tasks and bugs on all levels below the top feature - but not the features itself on the way down the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Sad story is that you can't make charts for this type of query, for exapmle to see % of bugs/tasks completed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33472485)